# How to stop stream from ending

Tags: cyclejs, xstream-js

How to stop the `take` method from ending nested streams, to be used with flatten?

Is there some other solution to nested streams? I tried merging `fromDiagram` without end symbol, but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got told that xs.never() is method specifically for this use case, and while I still don't know why fromDiagram would fail, I suppose that is an answer enough.

`xs.merge(stream.take(1), xs.never()).map(nestedStream)`